# variable of scope $http undefined in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$http({
url: "php/load.php",
method: "GET",
params: {'userId':userId}
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.mydata = data;
    mydata = data;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
});
```

strange, why $scope.mydata and mydata can't be access outside of $http scope? it's understandable $scope.mydata can't be access but why a global variable - mydata is too undefined?

Comment: where is mydata defined?

Comment: Maybe you're checking mydata BEFORE success event of $http. Remember that $http is asynchronous.

Comment: Above looks fine to me... `$scope.mydata` should be available anywhere within the controller.

Comment: @AlexandreTRINDADE your saying make sense. I placed both of them witin the my controller, the $http is later then my console.log(mydata), so It's undefined. So, what should I do?

Comment: Try check mydata by clicking a button somewhere after $http call.

Comment: @AlexandreTRINDADE if that work it doesn't solve my problem. I load the data from backend. I also tried to put ng-init somewhere in the view and put the $http witin an init function, doesn't work though.

Comment: Instead of a global variable you can use $rootScope. It is like a global variable that can be access from any $scope.

Comment: $rootScope.data = data? like this?

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the `mydata` variable not being accessible from outside the `$scope` of `$http` is due to the nature of the way that angular js works.

If you want the variable accessible outside of the `$scope` the you will need to change

`mydata = data;`

to

`window.mydata = data;`

Comment: if you don't use `"use strict";` then these two lines are equivalent